# how to add data from mysql table to C# form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

i have a wfa which has a datagridview which displays data from the mysql database the fields of the data is as follows o_id,name,address,contact_number,venue
when i click on a particular row i want all the fields of that row to populate the various text boxes on the other form with individual fields. example  one textbox should contain o_id, another textbox should contain name and so on. how can i achieve this.

i have tried the below code

```
 int SelectedRowndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
 string cid= dataGridView1.Rows[SelectedRowndex].Cells["o_id"].Value.ToString();
```

the above code gives me the o_id of te selected row. now using this i want to write a query which will separate all the other fields and store them into different strings so that i can assign them to the respective textbox in another form

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in multiple ways, that depends on the nature of ur app/requirement

1) instead storing just o_id in the data grid, you can store all the required data in the same row and hide(visible false) the coloumns that u dont need the client to show. so u r not required to acess the db again and again

2)you can execute a query to get the rest of the data on cell click event

*dont get the curentcell.rowindex

*use the following instead

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string id= dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        string sql = "select * from tb1 where id=" + id;
        ...............
        ...............
    }
```

Comment: the datagridview already shows all the data i just want to know the MySQL statement which will assign each value to different strings so that using those strings i can add these values to different text boxes in another form.